# Read-Only AD Group and Active Monitoring

Tags: outlook, active-directory, okta

My company wants to create a security group that allows us to drag and drop users, who have given a resignation notice or who will soon be terminated, into a read-only access group. Preferably the group with automatically monitor/audit the users in the specific group and log their activity. I am unaware if AD currently supports this or if OKTA has these features. Any advice or suggestions would be spectacular.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature natively available in AD. You would need to ensure that this group you create has read-only permissions on any resource that it ACLs and also remove the users from other groups that might grant read-write access.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping we wouldn't have to outsource for a monitoring service, but we might have to. Also I saw that there is a read-only and list-only permission so I'll try to make do with those in the meantime.